# How do I make sure my documentation is up to date with Spring Rest Docs?

Tags: json, spring, spring-restdocs

I really like the concept of using failed tests to ensure the documentation is up to date. But I don't know how to make it work for nested json. The way Spring REST Docs handles hierarchical payload seems to defeat the purpose:

> When documenting fields, the test will fail if an undocumented field is found in the payload. Similarly, the test will also fail if a documented field is not found in the payload and the field has not been marked as optional. **For payloads with a hierarchical structure, documenting a field is sufficient for all of its descendants to also be treated as having been documented.**

How would you write your tests for nested json so changes to the payload result in a failed test?

Example:

```
{
car: {
    motor : {
        brand: "Porsche",
        power: "165 kW"
    },

    suspension: {
        type: "automatic"
    }
}
```

Test:

```
.andDo(document("mytest", responseFields(
                    fieldWithPath("car").description("the car").type(JsonFieldType.OBJECT),
                    fieldWithPath("car.motor").description("the motor").type(JsonFieldType.OBJECT),
                    fieldWithPath("car.motor.brand").description("the motor brand").type(JsonFieldType.STRING),
                    fieldWithPath("car.suspension").description("the suspension"))))
```

A test with these response field definitions would pass even though car.motor.power and suspension.type are not defined. Is there a way to make it work? Multiple tests?

Answer (score 0):

The intent was to allow people to document all of the fields if they wanted, without forcing them to do so. However, as you have observed, it can lead to a new field in the API being missed. With hindsight, this was probably a mistake.

One way to avoid missing a new field is to only document "leaf" fields. In your example that would be:

- `car.motor.brand`
- `car.motor.power`
- `suspension.type`

You could do this in a separate test if you also wanted to keep the more detailed documentation. Another alternative would be to use something like JsonPath to assert the structure of the payload.

I realise that none of these is ideal so I've opened https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/issues/274.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply and action. It would be really great if you could resolve the issue. Maybe a solution would be to add a property to the FieldDescriptor so you you can en/disable strict checking per field?

For now I will probably try to solve it by using separate tests.

Comment: Wouldn't the test fail if brand is documented but power isn't?

Comment: No, I don't think so. If you've documented `car` or `car.motor` then everything beneath `car` or `car.motor` is considered as having been documented.

Comment: Perhaps the best solution here would be that all siblings of a documented field should be documented? So in that case if you document `car.motor`, `car.suspension` should be documented as well - but not any subfield of these two. If you document `car.motor.brand`, then you have to document `car.motor.power` as well. Consequently, if a new field is added in the payload, it will always be breaking your test unless you never documented a single field on the level it is added to.

Comment: @AndreasEvers
Interesting idea, but I think this is not the solution. Imagine I change car.motor.power like this:  
    `{
    car: {
    motor : {
        brand: "Porsche",
        power: {
            unit: "kW",
            amount: "165"
        },
    },
    suspension: {
        type: "automatic"
    }
}`
    
This will pass the test.