# Restdoc throws org.springframework.restdocs.snippet.SnippetException when trying to document child objects

Tags: java, mockmvc, spring-restdocs

I have an **OrderInfo** class:

```
@ApiModel(description = "object needed to make an order")

public class OrderInfo  implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @JsonProperty("purchase")
  private PurchaseInfo purchase = null;

  @JsonProperty("paymentMode")
  private PaymentMode paymentMode = null;

  @JsonProperty("serialNumber")
  private String serialNumber = null;

  public OrderInfo purchase(PurchaseInfo purchase) {
    this.purchase = purchase;
    return this;
  }

  @ApiModelProperty(required = true, value = "coming from commercialization")
  @NotNull
  @Valid
  public PurchaseInfo getPurchase() {
    return purchase;
  }

  public void setPurchase(PurchaseInfo purchase) {
    this.purchase = purchase;
  }

  public OrderInfo paymentMode(PaymentMode paymentMode) {
    this.paymentMode = paymentMode;
    return this;
  }

  @ApiModelProperty(required = true, value = "")
  @NotNull
  @Valid
  public PaymentMode getPaymentMode() {
    return paymentMode;
  }

  public void setPaymentMode(PaymentMode paymentMode) {
    this.paymentMode = paymentMode;
  }

  public OrderInfo serialNumber(String serialNumber) {
    this.serialNumber = serialNumber;
    return this;
  }


  @ApiModelProperty(value = "The serial number of the registered device")
  public String getSerialNumber() {
    return serialNumber;
  }

  public void setSerialNumber(String serialNumber) {
    this.serialNumber = serialNumber;
  }
}
```

Having a **PurchaseInfo** child object:

```
@ApiModel(description = "Info necessary to order a video, an episode or a season")

public class PurchaseInfo  implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @JsonProperty("id")
  private String id = null;

  @JsonProperty("pricingId")
  private String pricingId = null;

  @JsonProperty("price")
  private Double price = null;

  @JsonProperty("type")
  private ArticleType type = null;

  public PurchaseInfo id(String id) {
    this.id = id;
    return this;
  }


  @ApiModelProperty(required = true, value = "id of the commercialization")
  @NotNull
  public String getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public PurchaseInfo pricingId(String pricingId) {
    this.pricingId = pricingId;
    return this;
  }

  @ApiModelProperty(required = true, value = "additional pricing of the commercialization")
  @NotNull
  public String getPricingId() {
    return pricingId;
  }

  public void setPricingId(String pricingId) {
    this.pricingId = pricingId;
  }

  public PurchaseInfo price(Double price) {
    this.price = price;
    return this;
  }

  @ApiModelProperty(required = true, value = "price of the commercialization")
  @NotNull
  public Double getPrice() {
    return price;
  }

  public void setPrice(Double price) {
    this.price = price;
  }

  public PurchaseInfo type(ArticleType type) {
    this.type = type;
    return this;
  }

  @ApiModelProperty(required = true, value = "")
  @NotNull
  @Valid
  public ArticleType getType() {
    return type;
  }

  public void setType(ArticleType type) {
    this.type = type;
  }
}
```

And the generated corresponding **FieldDescriptor** classes:

```
public class OrderInfoFieldDescriptor {
    public static FieldDescriptor[] fdOrderInfo = new FieldDescriptor[] {
        fieldWithPath("purchase").description("coming from commercialization").type(PurchaseInfo.class),
        fieldWithPath("paymentMode").description("").type(PaymentMode.class),
        fieldWithPath("serialNumber").description("The serial number of the registered device").type(java.lang.String.class).optional()    };


    public static FieldDescriptor[] fdOrderInfoList = new FieldDescriptor[] {
        fieldWithPath("[].purchase").description("coming from commercialization").type(PurchaseInfo.class),
        fieldWithPath("[].paymentMode").description("").type(PaymentMode.class),
        fieldWithPath("[].serialNumber").description("The serial number of the registered device").type(java.lang.String.class).optional()    };
}
```

And:

```
public class PurchaseInfoFieldDescriptor {
    public static FieldDescriptor[] fdPurchaseInfo = new FieldDescriptor[] {
        fieldWithPath("id").description("id of the commercialization").type(java.lang.String.class),
        fieldWithPath("pricingId").description("additional pricing of the commercialization").type(java.lang.String.class),
        fieldWithPath("price").description("price of the commercialization").type(java.lang.Double.class),
        fieldWithPath("type").description("").type(ArticleType.class)    };


    public static FieldDescriptor[] fdPurchaseInfoList = new FieldDescriptor[] {
        fieldWithPath("[].id").description("id of the commercialization").type(java.lang.String.class),
        fieldWithPath("[].pricingId").description("additional pricing of the commercialization").type(java.lang.String.class),
        fieldWithPath("[].price").description("price of the commercialization").type(java.lang.Double.class),
        fieldWithPath("[].type").description("").type(ArticleType.class)    };
}
```

When mockMvc.perform is called in order to make a HTTP POST with requestBody and responseBody of type OrderInfo.class:

```
mockMvc.perform(postRequest)
                .andDo(document("orderInfoCreate", preprocessRequest(prettyPrint()), preprocessResponse(prettyPrint()),
                        pathParameters(parameterWithName("username").description("the name of the user")),
                        responseFields(OrderInfoFieldDescriptor.fdOrderInfo),
                        requestFields(OrderInfoFieldDescriptor.fdOrderInfo))).andExpect(status().isCreated())
                .andExpect(content().json(orderInfoAsJson));
```

The validation works for *paymentMode* and *serialNumber* but fails for *purchase* with the following exception:

```
org.springframework.restdocs.snippet.SnippetException: The following parts of the payload were not documented:
{
  "purchase" : {
    "id" : "purchaseId",
    "pricingId" : "pricingId",
    "price" : 12.0,
    "type" : "EPISODE"
  },
  "serialNumber" : "serialNumber"
}
```

Even though the request body and the response body look fine:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /api/users/myUserName/orders
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json;charset=UTF-8", Host:"host:posrt", Accept:"application/json;charset=UTF-8", Cookie:"identity=cookieForTest"]
             Body = {"purchase":{"id":"purchaseId","pricingId":"pricingId","price":12.0,"type":"EPISODE"},"paymentMode":"POSTPAID","serialNumber":"serialNumber"}
    Session Attrs = {}
```

And:

```
MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 201
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json;charset=UTF-8"]
     Content type = application/json;charset=UTF-8
             Body = {"purchase":{"id":"purchaseId","pricingId":"pricingId","price":12.0,"type":"EPISODE"},"paymentMode":"POSTPAID","serialNumber":"serialNumber"}
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

The issue appeared after migrating from Spring Boot 1x to 2x.

Do you have any idea what the issue could be?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are relying on `purchase` to document both `purchase` and everything it contains, i.e. `purchase.id`, `purchase.pricingId`, `purchase.price`, and `purchase.type`. This worked in REST Docs up to and including 1.1 but it created a problem where people would accidentally miss documenting a nested field as they had documented its parent. This was discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38240818/how-do-i-make-sure-my-documentation-is-up-to-date-with-spring-rest-docs) and also in [this Spring REST Docs issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/issues/274). The issue introduced a change in REST Docs 1.2 where documenting a field no longer documents all of its descendants by default. You are affected by this change as upgrading to Spring Boot 2 means that you have also upgraded to REST Docs 2.

If you want to keep the existing behaviour and just use `purchase` to document both it and all of its descendants, you should replace `fieldWithPath` with `subsectionWithPath`. If you want to document everything beneath `purchase`, you should add extra descriptors for `purchase.id`, `purchase.pricingId`, `purchase.price`, and `purchase.type`.

Comment: You are right, REST Docs has been updated to 2.0.3. In this case, we want to keep the existing behavior and `subsectionWithPath` option did the job. Thank you for your help!